# Flask: injection of the "client" parameter using pytest fixture

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I just can't figure out how pytest determines the parameter "client" in the Flask test suite located in this [file](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/blob/master/tests/test_swagger.py).

```
class SwaggerTest(object):
    def test_specs_endpoint(self, api, client):
        data = client.get_specs("")
        assert data["swagger"] == "2.0"
        assert data["basePath"] == "/"
        assert data["produces"] == ["application/json"]
        assert data["consumes"] == ["application/json"]
        assert data["paths"] == {}
        assert "info" in data
```

I've looked in the conftest.py file in the same directory but there is no definition of a fixture for "client".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I see a fixture being used my immediate reaction like you, is to check the `conftest.py` file. Since it is not defined there, my next thought is to check the testing requirements which leads me to [this line](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/blob/master/requirements/test.pip#L8). After finding the documentation for `pytest-flask` we can see that [this fixture, `client`,](https://pytest-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#client-application-test-client) is defined as a fixture within that library.